# Not able to install opendr in python 3.6 Error in visual studio libs

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio

opendr is 3d renderer
I am trying to install opendr in my python 3.6 env for a 3D project but it giving some errors about Microsoft visual studio lib file.
I have tried to reinstall visual studio 2019 and also tried with the new python environment.
but reflecting the same error.
I am not much familiar with visual studio libs and ctx_mesa etc.
please help to resolve this issue
and ask if any other information required regarding this.

```
(c3dpo) C:\Users\Microsoft\Desktop\3D project\3D human pose>pip install opendr
Collecting opendr
  Using cached opendr-0.78.tar.gz (581 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in c:\users\microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\lib\site-packages (from opendr) (0.29.21)
Requirement already satisfied: chumpy>=0.58 in c:\users\microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\lib\site-packages (from opendr) (0.70)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\users\microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\lib\site-packages (from opendr) (3.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.13.0 in c:\users\microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\lib\site-packages (from chumpy>=0.58->opendr) (1.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.1 in c:\users\microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\lib\site-packages (from chumpy>=0.58->opendr) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in c:\users\microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\lib\site-packages (from chumpy>=0.58->opendr) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->opendr) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in c:\users\microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->opendr) (8.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->opendr) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->opendr) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.3 in c:\users\microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->opendr) (2.4.7)
Building wheels for collected packages: opendr
  Building wheel for opendr (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MICROS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pe33bdia\\opendr\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MICROS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pe33bdia\\opendr\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\MICROS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ooqqwxxr'
       cwd: C:\Users\MICROS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pe33bdia\opendr\
  Complete output (53 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\camera.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\cvwrap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\dummy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\everything.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\filters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\geometry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\lighting.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\occlusion_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\renderer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\serialization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\simple.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\slider_demo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\test_camera.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\test_depth_renderer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\test_geometry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\test_renderer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\test_sh.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\topology.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\util_tests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  copying opendr\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\contexts
  copying opendr\contexts\autogen.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\contexts
  copying opendr\contexts\draw_triangle_shaders_2_1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\contexts
  copying opendr\contexts\draw_triangle_shaders_3_2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\contexts
  copying opendr\contexts\fix_warnings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\contexts
  copying opendr\contexts\_constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\contexts
  copying opendr\contexts\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\contexts
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\test_dr
  copying opendr\test_dr\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\test_dr
  running build_ext
  building 'opendr.contexts.ctx_mesa' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\opendr
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\opendr\contexts
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D__OSMESA__=1 -Iopendr/contexts -I. -IC:\Users\Microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Iopendr/contexts/OSMesa/include -IC:\Users\Microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\include -IC:\Users\Microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcopendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.obj -lstdc++
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-lstdc++'
  ctx_mesa.c
  C:\Users\Microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
  opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.c(7070): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'GLint', possible loss of data
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:opendr/contexts/OSMesa/lib /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" OSMesa.lib GL.lib GLU.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_ctx_mesa build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\contexts\ctx_mesa.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\opendr/contexts\ctx_mesa.cp36-win_amd64.lib -lstdc++
  LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/lstdc++'; ignored
  LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'OSMesa.lib'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opendr
  Running setup.py clean for opendr
Failed to build opendr
Installing collected packages: opendr
    Running setup.py install for opendr ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MICROS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pe33bdia\\opendr\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MICROS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pe33bdia\\opendr\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MICROS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mnqz9xe2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\Include\opendr'
         cwd: C:\Users\MICROS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pe33bdia\opendr\
    Complete output (53 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\camera.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\cvwrap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\dummy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\everything.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\filters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\geometry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\lighting.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\occlusion_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\renderer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\serialization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\simple.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\slider_demo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\test_camera.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\test_depth_renderer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\test_geometry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\test_renderer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\test_sh.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\topology.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\util_tests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    copying opendr\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\contexts
    copying opendr\contexts\autogen.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\contexts
    copying opendr\contexts\draw_triangle_shaders_2_1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\contexts
    copying opendr\contexts\draw_triangle_shaders_3_2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\contexts
    copying opendr\contexts\fix_warnings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\contexts
    copying opendr\contexts\_constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\contexts
    copying opendr\contexts\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\contexts
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\test_dr
    copying opendr\test_dr\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\test_dr
    running build_ext
    building 'opendr.contexts.ctx_mesa' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\opendr
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\opendr\contexts
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D__OSMESA__=1 -Iopendr/contexts -I. -IC:\Users\Microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Iopendr/contexts/OSMesa/include -IC:\Users\Microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\include -IC:\Users\Microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcopendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.obj -lstdc++
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-lstdc++'
    ctx_mesa.c
    C:\Users\Microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.c(7070): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'GLint', possible loss of data
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:opendr/contexts/OSMesa/lib /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" OSMesa.lib GL.lib GLU.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_ctx_mesa build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\opendr/contexts/ctx_mesa.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\opendr\contexts\ctx_mesa.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\opendr/contexts\ctx_mesa.cp36-win_amd64.lib -lstdc++
    LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/lstdc++'; ignored
    LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'OSMesa.lib'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MICROS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pe33bdia\\opendr\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MICROS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pe33bdia\\opendr\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MICROS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mnqz9xe2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Microsoft\anaconda3\envs\c3dpo\Include\opendr' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.
It's often worth trying to disable cached copies. Try the following command and tell us the outcome:
`pip install opendr --no-cache-dir`

Comment: You can also download it from https://pypi.org/project/wheel/#files (first link, the file name is "wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl")
then `pip install "/the/filePath/to/wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl"`

Comment: yes tried both ways disable cache and install using wheel but error is same because error is related to visual studio libs i  think......

Comment: hm, I'm not sure of that from your output, and I wouldn't nkwo how to help in that case since you're on windows. But I would suggest you give one last try with `pip install --no-index --find-links="/the/filePath/to/wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl" wheel`, then `pip install opendr`

Comment: [According to PyPI, opendr 0.78 is only (officially) compatible with Python 2](https://pypi.org/project/opendr/). So it would need to be installed in a Python 2 virtual environment (excluding any other potential issues). However, there are at least two Python 3 forks that you might try -- [this one by polmorenoc](https://github.com/polmorenoc/opendr) and [this one by  SelvamArul](https://github.com/SelvamArul/opendr). Please note that I have not tested these personally, they were simply mentioned in a couple GitHub issues as unofficial Python 3 forks of opendr.